# Filtering static data in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a column which is populated based on a value in the `JSON`. I would like to filter the data based on the value I have displayed based on the value in the `JSON`. How can I achieve this?

```
JSON Data:
{
flip: {
image: "image1"
zone: "sing_tel"
},
environment: "development",
location: "sing11",
}

<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
          <input type="text" class="pull-right input-large global-search" placeholder="Search .." data-ng-model="searchNetwork.$">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="input-search">
          <input type="text" class="span12" data-ng-model="srchId" data-ng-change="delaySearch('id', srchId)" placeholder="ID .." />
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="input-search">
          <input type="text" class="span12" data-ng-model="srchLink" data-ng-change="delaySrch('href', searchLink)" placeholder="Net Link" />
        </th>
        <th class="input-search">
          <input type="text" class="span12" data-ng-model="srchLocation" data-ng-change="delaySearch('loc', srchLocation)" placeholder="Location" />
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="network in networkData | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:searchNetwork">
        <td>{{network.id}}</td>
        <td>{{network.location}}</td>
        <td>{{network.privacy}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`Flip` element in the above `JSON` is received only for some nodes to which I display the value as `FlipMe` in my `UI`. I would like to filter my data based on this column.

Comment: Any chance we can have a look at a bit of your code? The HTML maybe?

Comment: Just taking a guess that you're `ng-repeating` so maybe something like `ng-repeat="json in jsondata | filter:{flip: '!!'}"` This way it'll filter and not display those with a null or undefined `flip`.